# Using super.method() when you're not overriding the method?

Tags: java, methods, overriding, super

Is it common practice to always use super for calling methods out of the superclass, even when I'm NOT overriding the method?

Assume

```
public class Parent{
    public void method() {

    }
}
```

So

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    public void someMethod() {
        super.method();
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    public void someMethod() {
        method();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The leading question is easy to answer:

> Is it common practice to always use super for calling methods out of the superclass, even when I'm NOT overriding the method?

No, its not common practice. On the contrary, its *dangerously confusing* to do so. You call methods normally, because the main point of inheritance is to allow the classes to override methods to change/extend their behavior. You normally don't care about at which level a method is actually implemented.

The obvious exception is when you *do* override the method yourself and you *want/need* the parents functionality.

Now to the *dangerously confusing* part of explicitly calling super:

```
public class CallSuper {

    static class Parent {
        public void foo() {
            System.out.println("Parent.foo");
        }

        /** 
         * Calls foo to do the main work
         */
        public void bar() {
            System.out.print
            foo();
        }
    }

    static class Child extends Parent {
        public void foo() {
            System.out.println("Child.foo");
        }

        public void bar() {
            super.foo();
        }
    }

    static class GrandChild extends Child {
        public void foo() {
            System.out.println("GrandChild.foo");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Parent();
        Parent c = new Child();
        Parent g = new GrandChild();

        System.out.print("Parent.foo() = ");
        p.foo();
        System.out.print("Child.foo() = ");
        c.foo();
        System.out.print("GrandChild.foo() = ");
        g.foo();

        System.out.print("Parent.bar() = ");
        p.bar();
        System.out.print("Child.bar() = ");
        c.bar();
        System.out.print("GrandChild.bar() = ");
        g.bar();
    }
}
```

If you run this example it will output (added line numbers for clarity):

```
1 Parent.foo() = Parent.foo
2 Child.foo() = Child.foo
3 GrandChild.foo() = GrandChild.foo
4 Parent.bar() = Parent.foo
5 Child.bar() = Parent.foo
6 GrandChild.bar() = Parent.foo
```

The first four lines are not surprising, we get what foo implements at each level, respectively Parents's bar calling its foo. It starts to get odd at  line 5. Child bypasses its own override of foo by calling super.bar(), so while its foo() is specialized, bar() is not. In Line 6, you see that GrandChild inherits this oddity from Child, so the somewhat innocent looking super.foo() in Child's bar has now broken GrandChild's expectations that its override of foo() is effective for all bar() as well.

Now if you imagine foo() and bar() actually doing something *useful* and that they have a meaningful relationship with each other, e.g. you are led to believe (either by Parent's documentation or just common sense) that overriding foo() will change the behavior of bar(), too. Child's "super" is breaking that.

As a rule of thumb, if you see a "super.x()" call anywhere outside of an actual *override* of "x()", its probably an accident lurking to happen.

Answer (score 6):

Calling `super` tells the JVM to *explicitly* look to the parent class' version of a method.  Continuing with your example, if you just call

```
method()
```

The JVM will first search in the calling class for the method (in this case `Child`) before looking at the parent class.  On the other hand, if you call

```
super.method()
```

then the JVM will explicitly look at the parent class for an implementation, even if `Child` has an method called `method()`.

Putting these two ideas together, you should probably always use `super` when you intend to call the parent class' method.  If your class does not override the method, then you *could* call without `super`.  But even this becomes problematical if someone were to refactor your class later on and override the method.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't seem to apply to the case that the OP asked.  The example suggests that the OP is asking about calling the super method from the child method.  This answer is about bypassing the child's implementation from calling code.

Comment: @Brick you don't understand my answer.

Comment: It should be noted that if you are not going to override some method (and control the superclass), it's much better to declare it `final`. In any case don't use `super` just to improve the performance. If JVM sees that the method is not overridden, the `method()` call in the hot code will become equally fast as `super.method()`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it common practice to always use super for calling methods out of the superclass? Or is it redundant code?

It's not redundant. It have a special purpose of invoking parent class method (*though you ovveriden*). When you don't want, don't invoke. If you current class is not child of that class, `super` won't work for you.

> Also if you call an overridden supermethod, does it use the supermethod or the lowest method?(in the inheritance tree)

The overridden method. Since you overridden it in your class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't know whether I should use super if I'm NOT overriding the method.

Comment: Sky, that really depends. If you really want to do something with super class method. I'm highly recommending the offcial docs  : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html . please read it.

Comment: You should use `super`.  Imagine that you or someone else later on decides to override `method()`.  Then your code might break if you were assuming that you are still calling the parent class' method (which you're not).

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I'm not sure what you mean by 'if you really want to do something with super class method', I'm calling it so obviously I want to use it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just realised that as well, thanks. You seem to be the first one who's not trying to confuse me :S

Comment: Sky, There are situations, where some super class business needs to be done before child starts it's business. Please go through the link given which is official docs. Now you are in a halfway. Go though and comeback with your doubts.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I'm not sure if you got my question, but I think I was pretty clear when I said 'when I'm NOT overriding the method?'.

Comment: Sky, You shouldn't use . Unless you need it.

Comment: Well now I don't know who is correct, TimBiegeleisen or @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ :S

Comment: @Sky Your both methods are correct. One is invoking super method. Other is not.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I am aware of that, as you can see in my question I was simply asking what best practice would be. But this discussion is rather pointless, as you appearantly still haven't read the question correctly. And plenty of people have given legit answers already.

Comment: @Sky Sure. Read them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not overriding, let's talk about performance.

If you call an inherited method in your class, let's say, `methodInSuperclass()`, the JVM will look for that method first in your class, then up the class hierarchy until it finds it.

Using `super.methodInSuperclass()` tells the JVM to go directly to the superclass to look for that method.

So, using the `super` keyword improves performance by a few mills. It's ugly code, but it's not redundant as it will bring some performance improvement.

Consider using it if time is critical.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the super method or not depends entirely on what you are trying to do.  If you want to do what the parent class did plus some additional action, then calling the super method is good.  If you're doing something completely different in the child implementation then do not call the super method.  When you do call the super method in a hierarchy of classes, it calls the one closest to your child class in the hierarchy.

In some cases you may have an API where calling the super method is part of the overall contract.  The `clone` method is such a case.

Comment: So is it common practice to use super even when you're NOT overriding the method?

Comment: @Sky If you're not overriding the method, I would say that it's rare to call the super implementation.  Arguably it breaks the OO design paradigm.  If there is no override, then it is redundant.  If an override is added later, you've bypassed that design decision, which will probably be the wrong thing to do in most cases. (Presumably the child class overrides for a reason.)  But in some cases it might make sense - I wouldn't want to suggest an absolute rule for such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

If Child is having the same version method with Parent, JVM will call the Child's version instead of Parent's version if without "super". The "super" keyword is helpful if you want to make sure the Child is always calling the Parent's version method.